# YouTube videos (using latest API) won't play on Chrome on Android?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api, mobile-chrome

I'm developing a site for a client and am stuck at this point, as both of us have been able to recreate this issue in Chrome on Android.

For whatever reason, when we load this page on Android in Chrome:

http://miso.gostppro.com

The video loader just keeps spinning and spinning and the video never plays.

And tapping it on it doesn't do anything either (doesn't start the play, doesn't open it in YouTube app, nothing).

It works just fine in other browsers (Firefox for Android loads it and plays it just fine), so I'm confused as to why this is happening.

What am I missing?

Is it some call in the API or something?

I'm lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, it won't work. Quoting the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations):

> The HTML5  element, in certain mobile browsers (such as Chrome
>   and Safari), only allows playback to take place if it's initiated by a
>   user interaction (such as tapping on the player). (...) Due to this
>   restriction, functions and parameters such as autoplay,
>   **playVideo()**, loadVideoById() **won't work in all mobile environments**.

You're calling `event.target.playVideo();` in your `onPlayerReady` handler, which is not allowed in mobile environments and throws a warning in console (for future reference - I highly recommend using [Remote Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) in Chrome).

So, back to your problem - I'd just get rid of the `onPlayerReady` handler and use `autoplay` player variable instead. It should work on desktops and not break the player on mobile either.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your webpage on my Nexus 5 running Android 5.1.1 and found a few issues:

First I was getting this error:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': https://www.youtube.com !== http://miso.gostppro.com

Which I thought was an http vs https error, but after I refreshed the page with error went away and I saw a new warning:

> Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.

As pointed out in jkondratowicz's answer, this is a byproduct of mobile browsers disallowing autoplay on HTML5 videos.  The only think I can think of is remove any JavaScript related to the player and the autoplay parameter and allow the user to manually start video playback when they're ready.

I was also getting mixed results results with adding an listener to the page load event which calls `play()` on the iframe:

```
function callback () {
    document.querySelector('ytplayer').play();
}

window.addEventListener("load", callback, false);
```